# Click visible button in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I have a page which looks something like this. It's a wizard with steps. Depending on the "step" scope variable, a different part of the wizard is shown:

```
<div ng-show="step == 'first'">
  <button>Next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="step == 'second'">
  <button>Next</button>
</div>

<div ng-show="step == 'third'">
  <button>Next</button>
</div>
```

To click the next button I run into problems though. Because there are three of them. The following code returns all of them:

```
var next = element(by.buttonText('Next'));
```

And doing:

```
next.click();
```

will click the first one. How can I find the visible button only, and click that one?

Comment: have you tried to check the elements by using `element.isDisplayed()` method? E.g. find all elements, then iterate trough all three elements and if `isDiplayed()` is true you click it?

Comment: If I do next.each(function(el) { if (el.isDisplayed() el.click();}); I get UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (383, 186). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: hmm another solution could be that you just catch the exception and stil perform a click on all three buttons. Not a clean solution but I can't think of another one yet

Comment: Seems like I was confused by isDisplayed(). It returns a promise and cannot be used without a then()-clause.

Answer (score 1):

First I was confused by isDisplayed returning a promise. This function is what I came up with:

```
function clickButton(text) {
    var buttons = element.all(by.buttonText(text));
    buttons.each(function(button) {
        button.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
            if (isVisible) {
                button.click();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
clickButton('next');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more cleaner version in terms of understanding that uses [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter a single visible button and click it:

```
function clickButton(text) {
    var buttons = element.all(by.buttonText(text));
    var visibleButton = buttons.filter(function(button) {
        return button.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
            return isVisible;
        });
    }).first();
    visibleButton.click();
}
```

As a bonus, you'll also get an error if there are no visible buttons found, as opposed to your current approach which would not fail in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain the elements to specify which next button you want to click.

```
var firstNext = element(by.css('div[ng-show="step == \'first\'"]')).element(by.buttonText('Next'));

var secondNext = element(by.css('div[ng-show="step == \'second\'"]')).element(by.buttonText('Next'));

var thirdNext = element(by.css('div[ng-show="step == \'third\'"]')).element(by.buttonText('Next'));

// We are on the first step
firstNext.click();

// We are on the second step
secondNext.click();

// We are on the third step
thirdNext.click();
```